# Best Free 3D modelling Software

Tags: 3d

i need to create a triangle based prism in a 3d software however i do not know which one to use can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could consider using 'Blender' wich is a free, easy to use 3d modelling software, with enough online tutorials, and documentation.